# SonarQube API - multiple metrics for all components/projects

Tags: sonarqube

I'd like to retrieve multiple metrics for ALL projects in SQ in one GET request. Is this possible?

It seems like GET api/measures/component can give me the XML I want, but only if given a specific componentKey (project name). The only other alternative seems to be to go one by one through each component, which wouldn't be ideal given that I have over 500 projects I would like get metrics for.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible. You'll have to query the api/measures/component many times to get all measures from all projects.

Comment: Is this still the case today in 2022 with the new LTS?

Comment: Yes @Ivan it's still the case. If you feel an important use case is missing, feel free to post a new thread on the community forum (https://community.sonarsource.com/c/sq/10), with details about your use case. Thanks!